# Synonym for 'to follow up on something'

Tags: synonyms

Regarding ['to follow up'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/follow+up+on+something), I prefer a one-word synonym for want of concision.
Example: I am writing (or calling) **to follow up** on the earlier missive.

Comment: _Pursue_ is one possibility. Or _follow up_ itself.

Comment: There is no reason whatever to believe that *follow up on* needs to be replaced with a single word. It's amazing what people will *put up with* in the name of some quijotesque crusade against using simple words in simple ways. Phrasal  verbs are part and parcel of the English language. They are not something one should try to *do without*.

Answer (score 3):

I would say :

[regarding](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regarding) the  earlier missive; with respect to, concerning.
"your recent letter regarding the above proposal"
Synonyms:   concerning, as regards, with/in regard to, with respect to, with reference to, relating to, respecting, re, about, apropos, on the subject of, in connection with, vis-à-vis ([Wikipedia](https://www.google.com/search?q=regarding&oq=regarding&aqs=chrome..69i57.2751j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)).

[pursuing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pursue) the earlier missive; to carry on or continue (a course of action, a train of thought, an inquiry, studies, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, *to pursue* and *to follow up* are quite standard. Here are a few more related words I remember using when I was working in a Software company:

- to seek.
- to track.
- to trace.
- to check progress.
- to get updates.
- to get status.
- to send a gentle reminder.
- to escalate.
- to torment *(a bit too strong!)*.